# Castle Windsor And Caliburn Mirco strange behavior when conducting

Tags: c#, wpf, castle-windsor, caliburn.micro

I have a strange behavior when combining Castle Windsor and Caliburn.Micro (latest versions). I have a `ShellViewModel` that is a Conductor for `IWorkspace`. When I start my application I have one (first implementation of `IWorkspace`) added to `ShellViewModel.Items` collection. Is this how it should be by default? Is my bootstrapper configured wrong?

AppBootstrapper.cs

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
     IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IShell>().ImplementedBy<ShellViewModel>());

        container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IWorkspace>().WithServiceAllInterfaces().WithServiceSelf().LifestyleTransient()
            );


        container.Register(Component.For<IEventAggregator>().ImplementedBy<EventAggregator>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IWindowManager>().ImplementedBy<WindowManager>());
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) ? container.Resolve(service) : container.Resolve<object>(key);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return new[] { container.ResolveAll(service) };
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
    }
}
```

ShellViewModel.cs

```
 public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IWorkspace>.Collection.OneActive, IShell
{

}
```

ShellView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CastleCaliburnTest.Shell.ShellView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CastleCaliburnTest.Shell"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="HotPink">
<Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items.Count}" FontSize="48"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Workspace1ViewModel.cs

```
 public class Workspace1ViewModel : IWorkspace
{
    public Workspace1ViewModel()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Workspace 1 created");
    }
}
```

Interfaces:

```
public interface IShell: IConductor, IGuardClose
{

}
public interface IWorkspace
{

}
```

Comment: Do you have the BuildUp() override in the bootstrapper?

Comment: As an add on I would say it appears to be correctly configured, I don't personally use windor. So many examples are out there.  One thing is that if you plan on using Conductor, each "workspace" will need some sort of lifecycle, Screen or IScreen as part of your baseviewmodel for the individual workspaces as you build up your application.

Comment: I don't override the BuildUp() method. Adding ISceen to IWorkspace is just something that I forgot in this simple sample. However the problem/issue is still as long as I am conducting IWorkspace Castle or Caliburn are resolving that interface and adding it to the Items collection. This is done automatically and not by my code where I do ActivateItem(...) This behavior is what I want to get rid of. I can of course conduct object and not IWorkspace,

Comment: `Conductor<IWorkspace>.Collection.OneActive` does not automatically populate Items collection for the conductor.  You actually have to do it somewhere.  HelloScreens example shows that it has to be implicit.  Somewhere are you telling it to push into the collection.  So no it is not normal behavior.  I suggest you review the examples that exist for the combo of Winsor and CM.  Unfortunately alot of them are built on 1.52 which is alas really old in design.  So you will probably have to refactor the code to 2.01

Comment: That's what I also would expect, but I posted the whole project (did not post app.xaml) here which replicates this behavior. As you can see in ShellView.xaml I am printing out the current count. When the application launches it prints 1 and adding a contentpresenter binding to ActiveItem it renders Workspace1View.xaml (This xaml is just a textblock saying workspace 1) So I cannot see where in this small testproject where I am calling this.